# How do I export certain data from a website in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I'm trying to extract information from a website but I'm running into a little bit of trouble. I'm trying to extract the Characters Name, Corporation, and Ship type but running into trouble of how to pinpoint it.

Here is an example link: https://zkillboard.com/kill/74856710/

```
Character Name: Iridescent klr
Corporation: Association of Commonwealth Enterprises
Ship: Magus
```

Those are the criteria I'm trying to capture.

Currently, I've tried to do the code:

```
    =IMPORTXML(URL,xpath_query)
```

With no luck. I have however tried the:

```
    =IMPORTHTML(URL,"table",2)
```

And found that grabs the entire section, then Table 3 grabs the rest of the information but I'm not 100% how I could parse out the data of what I need as Character Names/Corporations/Ships have different variances.

The end goal of what I would like it to look like is as follows:

```
  A             |     B           |       C        |     D
  URL(ZkillLink   Character Name     Corporation        Ship
```

Any help would be completely awesome! Please let me know if I need to expand on this or give any more additional info.

-Maykid

Comment: Can you provide ``xpath_query`` you are using?

Comment: @Tanaike It's to a 'a href' link within a <td>, so for example: `<td> <a href="/character/2056506789/">Iridescent klr</a>`

Comment: @player0 the "Corporation" in the given example is if you follow the link is the following: Character `Iridescent klr` / Corporation: `Association of Commonwealth Enterprises` / Alliance: `Goonswarm Federation` / Ship: `Magus`

Comment: @player0 Alliance I don't think should be needed, just Character, Corporation, Ship should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A2, "table", 2), 1, 3), CHAR(10), 1, 1), 1, 2), 
                        INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A2, "table", 3), 1, 2)}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This works perfect!! So just trying to understand the code behind this, could you explain a little bit? For example I understand the importhtml at table 2, but the index, how do you know it's at 1, 3, char(10) etc. That would help out greatly!

Comment: sure! coz when you put this into A1: `IMPORTHTML(A2, "table", 2)` you got your data in 3rd column so you need to INDEX it eg skip first two columns. then your data are all in one cell so you need to SPLIT it by CHAR10 and CHAR10 is code for "new row" so you split by each row in given cell. then you dont need alliance so you ARRAY_CONSTRAIN it to drop of the 3rd (alliance) cell from SPLIT. and then you nest it with ship data and put all of it in array brackets `{}` separated by `,` so it would be next to each other

Comment: Ah okay! Awesome that makes a lot more sense thank you! One more question, is it possible to do a `LEFT` Function within the array? The reason why I ask this is to possibly only grab anything before the `(Command Destroyer)` and only have `Magus`, I've tried a couple variances but its giving me errors.

Comment: @Maykid no, that would be nasty, but you can regex it out: `={ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A2, "table", 2), 1, 3), CHAR(10), 1, 1), 1, 2), 
           REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A2, "table", 3), 1, 2),"\(([A-Za-z ]+)\)","")}`

Comment: Awesome I didn't even think about using regex, that works out perfectly! Thank you so much again! Very much appreciated!